# Make joomla load a module only once

Tags: html, css, joomla

So I have this custom module which contains a splash page (it's a blue 100% width 100% height screen with some animated images with the help of CSS). The splash page is set to only appear on main menu page (3 languages). The problem is that it also appears when I enter the main menu from some other website's page (Contacts etc.).
What I want is for the module to only show up only once for an user, so if he enters a main page again, he wouldn't see the splash. Is it possible to do so in joomla?

Comment: It is not so clear to me what you want to do. You want this module display only on the homepage, or you want display it only once for each visitor in any page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but this is a feature that you should handle with frontend code only.  You need to use javascript to check a cookie every time the page loads.  If the cookie exists, do nothing, else show the splash and set a cookie with duration = 1 year or whatever is appropriate.

You should set the css of the splash screen to

```
display:none
```

and then show it with the javascript.

Depending on your personal preference you could use javascript or a jQuery library for handling the cookies.  [Here's](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#script) a plain js example.

If you were using those functions, your script would be like

```
if (readCookie('showsplash')==null) {
    document.getElementById('splashscreen').style.display='block';
    createCookie('showsplash','off',360);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have some jQuery code of my own so it wasn't very compatable (I guess I can't mix jQuery and JS a lot (I'm a beginner (lol))). But the code works just as I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: You can mix it all you want - after all jQuery is written in javascript; of course you'd better copy off existing examples to start with; remember that Joomla often loads mootools with the "$" prefix, so you're safer using jQuery() instead of $()

Comment: sorry for bothering, I have one more question. I thought, that your code will make the cookie expire after 360 seconds. That's what I would want, so that if you leave the website and visit it again later - the splash screen would appear again, but it doesn't seem to do so. May you explain why is the code not doing it and help me to get a code which would make the cookie expire after 6 minutes?

Comment: And one more thing, where the script should be included, the `head` or the ending of the page?

Comment: All scripts should go in the footer, since the page will load faster; unless you want to ensure that the splash is already shown when the page first loads, but then you will have to wait for the script to be loaded each and every time the users surfs to another page. So it's a matter of requirements where you put it.

Comment: My code is using the referenced library which accepts days as input, not seconds; thus 360 is 360 days.  5 minutes would be 1/24/60*5 = 0.00347